# Rewrite Button in PHP Submission

Tags: javascript, forms

This may be one of the simplier questions. However, I can't get my head around it.

I have a Button in a form:

```
<button id='button' type="submit" class="btn" >Submit</button>
```

On form submission, I'd like to change the "Submit" into "Checking" because my submission check takes 1-2 seconds to finish.
So I tried echoing the following (located at the beginning of my form_submission.php):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
      var el = document.getElementById('button');
      el.firstChild.data = 'Checking Inquiry';
      </script>";
```

However, it doesn't do anything. Can someone help?

EDIT:

PHP verification:

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) &&  $_POST['email'] != '') {
$message_sent = true;
}
else {
$message_sent = true;
$invalid_class_mail = "form-invalid";
}
```

In HTML:

```
<?php
if($message_sent):
?>

<h3> We've revieced your inquiry! </h3>

<?php
else:
?>

<form .....>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="email" class="form-label">Your Email *</label>
   <input <?= $invalid_class_mail ?? "" ?> type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="jane@doe.com" tabindex="2" required>
   </div>
...
</form>
```

Comment: That's not how it works on StackOverflow. You can not change the question after an answer is placed, because now it may be wrong.

Comment: To Edit-2: It does work, but you submit the form again, which will trigger an infinite loop setting the text back to 'Checking Inquiry'.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I don't know, what you mean. I actually did not change the question in any way. My question still is about changing the button from "Submit" to "Checking Inquiry".
Ok, how would I overcome this loop?

Comment: 1) Yes, you first asked on how to change the text of the button, and then you edited the question after I answered. One problem, one question. Another problem, another question - not editing the old one. 2) Yes, the infinite loop comes from triggering the submit event again in the submit handler.

Comment: @MarkusZeller That's why I marked my edits, but they are part of the same problem? Ok, I changed ```document.getElementById('formnew').submit(function(e) {``` with ```document.getElementById('formnew').addEventListener('submit', function(e){```. But now, the form is not submitting?

Comment: please ask a new question, don't edit the current one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **innerText** property of an HTML element to change its content.

You may simplify like this.

```
document.getElementById('button').innerText = 'Checking Inquiry';
```

You also should either **listen on the submit event** on the form or the **button click event**.

#### Form

(when the form has in id attribute `id='form'`

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener(
    'submit', () =>
        document.getElementById('button').innerText = 'Checking Inquiry'
);
```

#### Button

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener(
    'click', (e) =>
        e.target.innerText = 'Checking Inquiry'
);
```

Comment: Hey! The ```document.getElementById('button').innerText = 'Checking Inquiry';``` inside the echo of PHP also doesn't do anything. And I need it inside my PHP script, because, when a verification of the form doesn't work the button should change back to "Submit".

Comment: If you echo it directly (after the button is created), it will change the content immediately, so you need to place it into an event handler. When you want to reset the button text, do it afterwards your submit task is complete. This has nothing to do with PHP, even if you output it via PHP.

Comment: And is there a way to change it back to "Submit", when the verification within PHP fails?

Comment: I think you are lacking the principle. PHP **cannot** change something what is brought to the browser. You could implement an AJAX request and change the text back on successful request. The part of PHP validation could be the answer (of the AJAX request) with an appropriate JSON.

Comment: Well that's true of course. I currently operating the answer of my PHP script as an ```form-invalid``` variable, when the verification fails. This form-invalid variable changes the coloring of my input fields, when something is missing. (I edited my original post, where you can see that). Is there something to do the same but only with the Button text?

Comment: @Soda — Only after the new page has loaded. You can't have the response to a request change the previous page while you wait for the response to load. Linear time doesn't work like that.

Comment: Ok, I implemented the form submission as an AJAX request. The PHP then echoes back "true" or "false" on verification. However, the button doesn't change at all. Please have a look at my second edit!

Comment: That's not how it works on StackOverflow. You can not change the question after an answer is placed, because now it may be wrong.